# When I customize the bitmap image in NSIS installer Welcome screen the updated bitmap image is not reflecting

Tags: nsis

As part of my project, when I customize the bitmap image in NSIS installer Welcome screen the updated bitmap image is not reflecting.

I used the below line to change the bitmap image:

```
 !define MUI_DEFAULT_MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "E:\Source\NULLSOFT\src\Bitmaps\dlgbmp.bmp"
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
    ;Pages
    ;Customizing the bitmap image
    
    !define MUI_DEFAULT_MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "E:\Source\NULLSOFT\src\Bitmaps\dlgbmp.bmp"
    
      !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
;Languages

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English" ; The first language is the default language
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "French"
```

Do we need to do any additional changes to update the new bitmap? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no define named `MUI_DEFAULT_MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP`, see the [MUI documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html) for valid defines.

In you case the define is named `MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP`:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\orange.bmp"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working with the changes you suggested.